# change a custom binding handler so that it is assigned using an IIFE

Tags: javascript, jquery, iife

I have a custom binding handler and want to modify it to IIFE. I have been reading on internet about IIFE but could not able how to change my custom handle into IIFE. So how can I change following binding handler into IIFE

```
define(['knockout', 'jquery'], function(ko, $) {
    ko.bindingHandlers.er = {
        init: function(el, va) {
            console.log($(el).find('.n').text());
            $(el).find('.edit').hide().end().find('.detail').show();
            $(el).find('.ebtn').on('click', function() {
                $(el).find('.edit, .detail').toggle();
            });
            $(el).find('.ubtn').on('click', function() {
                $(el).find('.edit, .detail').toggle();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Didn't you just make exactly the same question but deleted it?

Comment: I thought my previous question was not clear so I deleted that and tried to change to make it more clear.

Comment: Well this one is actually less clearer since you removed the module definition. And the original comments apply here fully as well.

Comment: And there's an 'edit' link near the 'delete' link, you could've used that, rather than creating an entirely new question with less information.

Comment: Since my question is about binding handler so I just added that code. Now I edited my question. Now can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite unclear what you're asking here :(.
Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) is an anonymous function that executes immediately. In your case, if you can't be more specific, it's really hard to guess where do you want to place the iife.
I normally put my whole code into an iife in order to take advantage of the function scope and use it as a closure, thus minimising the global object pollution and it generally looks like this :

```
(function(global,undefined){
    // the code goes here
    // global === window
})(this);
```

In your case, you can do the same :

```
 (function(global,undefined){
    define(['knockout','jquery'],function(ko,$){
        // ...
    });
})(this);
```

**Update :**
Here are some explanations for those who need them.
The following pattern is used:

- to prevent global variable leaks such as `var foo = bar;` (after which `window.foo === foo`)
- to prevent the `undefined` value to get overwritten. Let's say you want to check if something is undefined. you have 2 ways to do it :

  - `typeof foo === 'undefined'`
  - `foo === undefined`
    the second one is shorter but is often not preffered because one can simple overwrite the `undefined` variable's value : `undefined = 13;`.
    By not proviiding an actual value for the `undefined` argument in the iife, you're actually resetting the `undefined` variable to undefined.
- to generalize the global object

  - some say that the access to the `global` variable is faster than to the `window` object due to the fact that the js engine first looks into the lower scope
  - if you're running the code in a different environment than the browser and you have calls to the `window` object, your code might break because the global object is different from environment to ennvironment (adobe pdfs, node js, rhino ... ). This can be solved by remaping the global object to a variable (in our case `global`), by reffering it to the `this` object from the global scope

Comment: thanks @gion_13. Could you please tell me about params i.e. global and undefined?

Comment: Why should he do this? This is completely pointless with the `define`

Comment: @Esailija everyone codes in it's own way. I said I usually wrap **my** whole script into an iife like that and it seemed the only logical way to embed his handler into one.

Comment: @gion_13 yes I understand that but my point is that the point of using `require.js` and `define` is that you don't need this. It's like writing a for loop that doesn't do anything for no reason at the top of your code. Do you see my point? The function you pass to `define` is the "IIFE" in require.js

Comment: @gion_13 is it required to to pass undefined and global paramters? because when I removed them it is still working fine. will this be consider a good practice to remove them?

Comment: @al0neevenings I've explained their role in my update. The're not necessary, but can be useful.

Comment: @Esailija I know, but I was just answering the guy's question. There might be cases where the code **needs** an additional closure : say you have this code `define(...)` and your boss tells you to use another lib instead of *require.js*... you'll have to make some big changes. In order to make the code more extensible, you can write it as :`(function(define){define(/*...*/);})(window.definingModule)`. this way you can easily make major modifications with minor **code** modifications. Adding another layer of abstractisation won't kill your code, it will just make it more extendable!

Comment: @gion_13 yeah it's very useful when you are not using require.js or similar. I was just saying in a situation where you are using require.js, it's useless :) And I do appreciate you answering this impossible question.